# Java: How to show/hide a working indicator in a web app while place change?

Tags: java, gwt, web-applications

I´m looking for a way to show and hide a working indicator in my web application. I use GWT with model view presenter pattern and have places for my different pages and activities, which are my presenter objects.

What I tried so far:

View objects have to implement an

```
public interface HasWorkingIndicator 

void showWorkingIndicator(boolean show);
```

Activity objects call the showWorkingIndicator on their view object in a start method.

```
     @Override
     public void start(final AcceptsOneWidget panel, EventBus eventBus){
         page.showWorkingIndicator(true);
         //more code...
     }
```

So what is the best way to hide the WorkingIndicatorView? I cant call showWorkingIndicator(false) at the end of the start(), because the page is not set up at that time. 
Maybe any patterns to look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using activities this becomes a pretty easy task to accomplish.

I have an AbstractActity that implements Activity, this handles things like my clientfactory and the parent panel.

The Activity interface implements mayStop(), onStop and onStart etc.

```
public class WorkingIndicator extends Composite {

    private static WorkingIndicator instance = null;

    private WorkingIndicator(){
       initWidget(new Label("Working"));
    }

    public static WorkingIndicator getInstance() {
       if (instance == null) {
          instance = new WorkingIndicator();
      }
      return instance;

    }

    public void show() {
        RootLayoutPanel.get().add(this);
    }

    public void hide() {
        RootLayoutPanel.get().remove(this);
    }

}
```

The activity would look something like this.

```
public abstract class AbstractActivity<T extends ApplicationPlace, V extends View> implements Activity {

    protected ClientFactory clientFactory;
    protected EventBus eventBus;
    protected AcceptsOneWidget parentPanel;
    protected final T place;
    protected final V display;

    protected final List<HandlerRegistration> handlers = new ArrayList<HandlerRegistration>();


    public AbstractActivity(T place, ClientFactory clientFactory, V display) {
        this.place = place;
        this.clientFactory = clientFactory;
        this.display = display;
    }

    protected void setEventBus(EventBus eventBus) {
        this.eventBus = eventBus;
    }

    protected EventBus getEventBus() {
        return this.eventBus;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(AcceptsOneWidget parentPanel, EventBus eventBus) {
        this.parentPanel = parentPanel;
        this.eventBus = eventBus;

        parentPanel.setWidget(display.asWidget());
        bindToView();
        WorkingIndicator.getInstance().hide();
    }

    public AcceptsOneWidget getParentPanel() {
        return parentPanel;
    }

    public T getPlace() {
        return place;
    }

    public V getDisplay() {
        return display;
    }

    public ClientFactory getClientFactory() {
        return clientFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Shortcut getter for the CSS style in Resources.
     *
     * @return
     */
    public Style style() {
        return clientFactory.getResources().style();
    }

    @Override
    public String mayStop() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
      cleanup();
      display.reset();
      WorkingIndicator.getInstance().show();
    }

  protected void addHandler(HandlerRegistration registration) {
    handlers.add(registration);
  }

    public List<HandlerRegistration> getHandlers() {
        return handlers;
    }

    protected void cleanup() {
        for (HandlerRegistration handler : handlers) {
            handler.removeHandler();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This function will be called immediately after adding the view to the
     * DOM. This function should be used to hook up click handlers, populate
     * HasData handlers and such.
     */
    protected abstract void bindToView();

    protected DaoRequestFactory daoRequestFactory() {
        return clientFactory.daoRequestFactory();
    }

    protected AnalyticsTaskRequest analyticsTaskRequest() {
        return clientFactory.daoRequestFactory().analyticsTaskRequest();
    }

    protected EventBus eventBus() {
        return clientFactory.getEventBus();
    }

    protected PersonProxy currentPerson() {
        return clientFactory.getCurrentPerson();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the singleton WorkingInicator class may be the best way to show/hide a panel from the view so that it doesn't fall out of scope.

Comment: to understand your approach...you have to use the binToView() because your workingIndicator is a singleton and it will show/hide the workingIndicator on the view in your subclass activities, right?

Comment: The bindToView is simply because I had many activities sharing the same code over and over. This made a clean way for me to not have to implement all the start, stop, cleanup methods over and over. The bind to view is to tell the implementing activity that it's view is loaded and it can do all the initialization. You don't have to implement it this way if you have a WorkingIndicator singleton class, you can call show/hide anywhere. This won't work if the working indicator is initialized within you activity because it's view will unload and indicator will be lost while next activity is loading

Answer (score 3):

It depends how/where/when you want to show the indicator.

If the goal is to show it at the place of the activity, then you have two choices: handle it in the view, or calling `setWidget` twice on the `AcceptsOnWidget` that's passed to the activity's `start()`: once with a *wait indicator* widget, then with the real activity's view.
If you can guarantee that there will always be an activity for the given *display region*, then you can also bake this in the `AcceptsOneWidget` implementation: when `setWidget` is called with a `null` you display the waiting indicator (a similar trick is to use an `IsWidget` whose `asWidget` returns `null` instead of a *waiting indicator* widget in the activity's `start`).

If however you can live with a global indicator, then you can use a `NotificationMole` or similar widget, and trigger its showing depending on pending RPC/RequestFactory calles and/or events you'll dispatch on the event bus  from the activities.

Comment: thanks for this solution. I tried the first one, but I cant import the package of my WorkingIndicatorView into the Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Places change instantly. I assume you want to show an indicator when (A) the view is being constructed for the first time, or (B) you wait for data to arrive from your server before showing a view.

In either case you need to add a flag to your view, e.g. isInitialized(), to tell the activity if it needs to do something to build the view (like create a DataGrid, populate a tree, etc.), or the view has been already built before so this step can be skipped.

When your activity starts, check if the view is initialized. If not, show a loading indicator. I recommend a simple PopupPanel with a glass enabled to block the UI. When the activity finishes building the view/loading data, it should set the flag in the view (e.g. setInitialize()), and then you hide this popup panel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I´ll try this when I fail with the other approaches.